# WebView is not showing the background image in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I am trying to show some HTML content from an URL. My problem is the background image is not showing in the WebView.

My URL is "http://localhost/clients/gdc4gpat.in/home/get_answers/431"

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background-image: url('http://localhost/clients/gdc4gpat.in/assets-site/images/gdc_bg1.png') !important;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-position:center top;
                background-attachment:fixed;
            }
            .question{
                padding: 5px 0px;
            }
            .option{
                padding: 10px 0px;
            }
            .answer-div{
                color:white;
                padding: 10px 0px;
            }
            .answer, .correct{
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .bg-red{
                background-color: red;
            }
            .bg-green{
                background-color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (2):</b></span><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>In non-flocculated suspension, the particle exists as</strong></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><strong>Aggregation</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><strong>Cake&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><strong>Separate entities&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><strong>Coalescence&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : C</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : </span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (3):</b></span><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>Example of alcohol volatile oil</strong></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><strong>Peppermint&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><strong>Cinnamon</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><strong>Lemon peel</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><strong>Orange peel&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : A</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : </span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (4):</b></span><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>Which of the following pairs of compound is used as solvents in UV spectroscopy</strong></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><strong>Water, 95 % ethanol, Hexanal</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><strong>Acetonitrile, Chloroform, 1,4 Dioxane</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><strong>Methanol, Isooctane, Trimethylphosphate&nbsp;</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><strong>All are correct&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : D</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : B</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (5):</b></span><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>Lemon grass oil is obtained from</strong></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><strong>Cymbopogan flexuousus</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><strong>Pinus roxburghii&nbsp;</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><strong>Cymbopogan nardus&nbsp;</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><strong>Cymbopogan martini&nbsp;</strong></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : A</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : C</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (6):</b></span><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>The transition energy order in ultraviolet spectroscopy by organic molecules is </strong></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><strong>n</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&pi;*&gt;&pi;</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&pi;*&gt;n</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&sigma;*&gt;&sigma;</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&sigma;*</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><strong>n&rarr;</strong><strong>&pi;*&gt;&pi;</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&pi;*&gt; &sigma;</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&sigma;*&gt;n</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&sigma;*</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><strong>&sigma;</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&sigma;*&gt;n</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&sigma;*&gt; &pi;</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&pi;*&gt; n</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&pi;*&nbsp;</strong></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><strong>&sigma;&rarr;</strong><strong>&sigma;*&gt;&pi;</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&pi;*&gt; n</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&sigma;*&gt; n</strong><strong>&rarr;</strong><strong>&pi;*&nbsp;</strong></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : C</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : B</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (7):</b></span><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>Which of the following is bronchodilators</strong></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Corticosteroids</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Salmeterol&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Ketotifen&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Sodium cromoglycate&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></b></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : B</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : C</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (8):</b></span><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>Drave test is associated with measuring the efficiency of </strong></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Detergent&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Wetting agent&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Suspending agents&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Absorbent&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></b></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : B</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : C</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (9):</b></span><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>Artemisia annua comes under the class</strong></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Sesquiterpenoids&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Monoterpenoids&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Diterpenoids</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Tritepenoids&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : A</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : C</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (10):</b></span><p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"><strong><span style="color:#FF0000;">Determine the correctness or otherwise of the following Assertion [a] and the Reason [r] &ndash;<br />
Assertion (a) : </span>Terpenoid are basically originated from Isoprene unit<br />
<span style="color:#FF0000;">Reason (r) :</span> Every Isoprene unit contain C5H8</strong></p>
</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Both (a) and (r) are true, and (r) is a correct reason for (a)</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><b><font face="Cambria">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Both (a) and (r) are true, and (r) is NOT the correct reason for (a)</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><b><font face="Cambria">&nbsp; (a) is true but (r) is false</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><b><font face="Cambria">&nbsp; Both (a) and (r) are false&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : B</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : A</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (11):</b></span><strong><span style="color:#FF0000;">&ldquo;Holy basil&rdquo; is the synonym for drug</span></strong></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><i><b>Alpina officinarum</b></i><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><b><i>Allium sativum</i></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><i><b>Nardostachys jatamonum</b></i><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><i><b>Ocium sanctum</b></i><b> </b></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : D</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : C</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (12):</b></span><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>Bioassays are carried out to</strong></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Measure the pharmacological activity of a drug&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Avoid clinical trial for new drugs&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Detect the impurity in a given drug&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Screen for pharmacogenetic influence of new drugs&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : A</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : B</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (13):</b></span><p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"><strong><span style="color:#FF0000;">Given are four statements about spectral analysis -&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><br />
[P] Bathochromic shift -The wavelength change to longer wavelength&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
[Q] Hypsochromic shift - The wavelength change to shorter wavelength&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
[R] Hyperchromic shift - The absorption intensity is decreased&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
[S] Hypochromic shift - The absorption intensity is decreased&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
Choose the correct combination of statements </strong></p>
</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><b><font face="Cambria">P, Q &amp; R are true while S is false&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Q, R &amp; S are true while P is false</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><b><font face="Cambria">P, Q &amp; S are true while R is false</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><b><font face="Cambria">All are correct</font></b></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : C</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : A</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (14):</b></span><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Cambria&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">Soap from divalent base produces &hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;.emulsion </span></strong></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><b><font face="Cambria">o/w</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><b><font face="Cambria">w/o&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Both&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><b><font face="Cambria">None&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : B</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : C</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (15):</b></span><p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Cambria&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">Myristicin chemically is</span></strong></span></p>
</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Methoxy safrole&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Ethoxy safrole&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Propyoxy saffrole&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><b><font face="Cambria">Dimethoxy saffrole&nbsp; </font></b></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-red">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : A</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : C</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (16):</b></span><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Cambria&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">Determine the correctness or otherwise of the following Assertion [a] and Reason [r] -</span></strong></span>
<p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"><strong><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Cambria&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;
mso-ascii-theme-font:major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin;mso-bidi-font-family:
Mangal;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi"><span style="color:#FF0000;">Assertion [a] :</span><font color="#000000"> All pharmacokinetics processes involve transport of drug across biological </font></span></strong><strong><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Cambria&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;
mso-ascii-theme-font:major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin;mso-bidi-font-family:
Mangal;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi"><font color="#000000">membrane</font></span></strong></p>

<p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"><strong><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Cambria&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;
mso-ascii-theme-font:major-latin;mso-hansi-theme-font:major-latin;mso-bidi-font-family:
Mangal;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi"><span style="color:#FF0000;">Reason [r] : </span><font color="#000000">Biological membrane is a bilayer of phospholipids and cholesterol</font></span></strong></p>
</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="option"><span>(A)</span><span style="font-size:14px;"><b><font face="Cambria">&nbsp;&nbsp; Both (a) and (r) are true but (r) is not the correct reason for (a)</font></b></span></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(B)</span><span style="font-size:14px;"><b><font face="Cambria">Both (a) and (r) are true but (r) is the correct reason for (a)</font></b></span></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(C)</span><span style="font-size:14px;"><b><font face="Cambria">Both (a) and (r) are false</font></b></span></div>
                            <div class="option"><span>(D)</span><span style="font-size:14px;"><b><font face="Cambria">&nbsp; (a) is true but (r) is false</font></b></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 answer-div bg-green">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="correct">Correct Answer : A</span></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"><span class="answer">Your Answer : A</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solution"></div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="question"><span><b>Question (18):</b></span><span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>Stomata&nbsp; present in Fennel</strong></span></div>
                        </div>                            
                                                
                        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

WebView:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
```

Android Activity:

```
 WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);          
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gdc_bg1);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: That sounds great. What's your question?

Comment: My Problem is : Background image is not showing in webview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to changed that to:

```
                background-image: url('assets/image/gdc_bg1.png') !important;
```

Because there is not any localhost on a mobile phone with that file only on your desktop. So you need add to your assets folder. So you can load it from there.

Comment: Okey if it worked vind the answer as solved so people know it. I am really glad I could helped.